# getIntent() Extras always NULL

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent

I wrote a simple Android App that show a custom Notification like this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();          
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification( R.drawable.icon, title, System.currentTimeMillis());  
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( context,  this.getClass()); 
notificationIntent.putExtra("com.mysecure.lastpage", "SECURECODE"); 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context , 0, notificationIntent, 0);               
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notifypbar);
notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;

notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notifypb_status_text, text);
notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.notifypb_status_progress, 100, (int)(100*progress), false);

manager.notify(104, notification);
```

This piece of code is called ONLY ONCE in my application and it displays a notification with a progress bar (all correctly).

Now, when a user clicks on this notification my application handles the `onResume` event.

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    // TODO: Extras è SEMPRE NULL!!! impossibile!
    Intent callingintent = getIntent(); 
    Bundle extras = callingintent.getExtras();
```

but extras is always NULL!

I've tried any combination of:

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("com.mysecure.lastpage", "SECURECODE");
```

or

```
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putString(key, value);
notificationIntent.putExtra(extra);
```

but getIntent().getExtras() returns always NULL.

Comment: Did you try to set the Application Context within the Notification?

Answer (score 122):

This is the scenario:
The method `getIntent()` returns the FIRST intent than launch activity.

So, when the activity is CLOSED (terminated) and the user clicks on the notification, it will run  a new instance of the activity and `getIntent()` works as expected (Extras is *not* `null`).

But if the activity is "sleeping" (it is in the background) and the user clicks on the notification, `getIntent()` always returns the very FIRST intent that started the activity and NOT the notification intent.

So to catch the notification intent while the application is running, simply use this

`notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

and then override `onNewIntent(Intent newintent)`.

So when an application first runs, `getIntent()` can be used and when application is resumed from sleeping, `onNewIntent` works.

Comment: The following worked for me: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: in my case, add more android:launchMode="singleTask" in launcher activity. Thank you!

Answer (score 101):

Just Write this code above your on top of your Resume() method. This is all it takes. This refreshes intent - I don't really know, but it works.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

**Problem:** You are sending the same request code for your pending intens. Change this.

**Solution**: Set global variable int UNIQUE_INT_PER_CALL =0 and when you create pendingIntent call like below.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, UNIQUE_INT_PER_CALL, notificationIntent, 0);
UNIQUE_INT_PER_CALL++; // to increment.
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it seems your activity is already running, I think you need to specify `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, otherwise the `getIntent()` call will return the previous one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514750/android-clicking-on-notification-in-status-bar-binds-the-intent-with-the-target).

Comment: However i had no "PREVIOUS ONE" intent in my application. That piece of code will be called only ONCE and no other intent will be created or updated after that.

Comment: All activities are started by intents, so there *has* to be a previous intent. Hah, I just saw your own answer, that is what I meant!

Comment: This is what solved it for me. here's where to set that flag: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Answer (score -10):

Look at [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for passing and retrieving persistent key/value pairs.

Comment: i do not need to store data into preferences. I use shared preferences for other purpose. I need to pass ExtraData througth Intent.

Comment: Actually, this is the only answer that worked for me. In my case, the intent is started from url using activity:scheme, I tried everything, including `savedInstanceState` without luck.