# Pending Intent extras are missing when receive

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have a problem with sending extras with Pending Intent. I'm adding extra String in my `StateCh` service and sending to my `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` starts as expected but the extra String I have put there is always missing.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

 String recMessage = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

 if(recMessage.equals("")) {
    Log.v("recMessage", "none");
  } else {
   Log.v("recMessage", "something");
  }
    // ..
 }
}
```

StateCh.java:

```
public class StateCh extends Service {

//...

   private void notificationU(String title, String text)  {

    //The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("message", "ssss");
    intent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     Notification noti2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setContentTitle(title)
     .setContentText(text)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.warning)
     .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
     .build();

     mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     mNotificationManager.notify(123456, noti2);
    }

    // ...      

}
```

Comment: What is `eguals`? it should be `equals`

Comment: Why `OnCreate`? `OnResume` is called always after `OnCreate`.

Comment: Solved! I've found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352281/getintent-extras-always-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the right answer for my problem asking one more time and more precisely in another topis, here: [Pending intent extras are received only when activity is paused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563265/pending-intent-extras-are-received-only-when-activity-is-paused) .Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

check using `TextUtils`

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(recMessage)) {

// here your require condition

}
```

Comment: This is not reason of the problem. if I replace this checkin code with `Log.v("message=",recMessage);` I would get `message=`.