# Pending intent extras are received only when activity is paused

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I'm sending extra string with pending intent from my `StateCh.java` to `MainActivity`. My expectation on it is to display dialog in `MainActivity` when pending intent with extra is arrived (notification is clicked). The problem is when i open the `MainActivity` and then I click the notification there is no extras inside pending intent and dialog isn't displayed. When I pause the `MainActivity` (by pressing back button) and click the notification again it works as expected.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 //...

  @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)   {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        String value1 = extras.getString("message");
        Log.v("alert", value1);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("title");
        alertDialog.setMessage(value1);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //startActivity(MainActivity.this.getIntent());

            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
 }
}
```

StateCh.java:

```
public class StateCh extends Service {

//...

   private void notificationU(String title, String text)  {

    //The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("message", "something");
    intent.setAction("actionstring" + System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     Notification noti2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setContentTitle(title)
     .setContentText(text)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.warning)
     .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
     .build();

     mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     mNotificationManager.notify(123456, noti2);
    }

    // ...      

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();`

To `Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();`

or call [setIntent(intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) first

Comment: Thanks! I can't belive it was so simple but it did the trick.