# I cannot get the Extras out of my Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I use an AlarmManager to start an activity via a PendingIntent.

```
        Intent smon = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        final Bundle extra = new Bundle();
        extra.putString("extrastring","monday");
        smon.putExtras(extra);
        //smon.putExtra("extrastring","monday");
        smon.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent psmon = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, smon, 0);

        Calendar calSet1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calSet1.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calSet1.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calSet1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        calSet1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hsmon);
        calSet1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, msmon);
        calSet1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        int delay1=0;
        if(today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)>2)delay1=7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        if((today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==2)&&(today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>hsmon))delay1=7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        if((today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==2)&&(today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)==hsmon)&&(today.get(Calendar.MINUTE)>msmon))delay1=7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        Log.e("delay 1",Integer.toString(delay1));
        //calSet.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet1.getTimeInMillis()+delay1,
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, psmon);
```

As you can see there is an Extra in my Intent: "extrastring".

Now, when I try tor read that Extra from the started Activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //
    final Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message="cazzo";
    if (extra != null) {

        message=extra.getString("extrastring");
    }
    Log.e("intent che è partito",message);
```

I get a NullPointerException.

Thanks for any help

```
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.videdrome/com.example.videdrome.VideoActivty}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at com.example.videdrome.VideoActivty.onCreate(VideoActivty.java:41)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-19 13:34:18.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14109):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Probably the `getIntent()` is returning `null`. Where are you calling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been doing the similar thing using Bundle

```
final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, A.class);
notificationIntent.putExtras(extra);
final PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

where extra is a Bundle :

```
final Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putString("Message", "hello");
```

You can retrieve the value of Bundle in onCreate of started Activity:

```
final Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extra != null) {
    String message=extra.getString("Message");
}
```

Moreover , you can use flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

This flag works like this:

if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but its replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent. This can be used if you are creating intents where only the extras change, and don't care that any entities that received your previous PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new extras even if they are not explicitly given to it.

Comment: I tried your way, that seems the most complete, but no Extras are delivered. If I try to extract the mentioned Extra I get null

Comment: Use the Flag that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is put that string into a `Bundle`, and add that to your Intent (using [putExtras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Then you can call [getExtras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) on your intent to get your Bundle back, from which you can get your string back.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     String message = extras.getString("extrastring");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
String result = getIntent().getExtras().getString("extrastring");
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, i suspect that the `NullPointerException` is caused because the `getIntent()` methiod returns `null`. There may be two possible reasons for this to happen:

1. Check that you are not calling `getIntent()` before the called Activity's `onCreate()` method is fired.
2. Keep in mind that if your called Activity is already open when you send the intent, it will not receive the new intent that you send but it will use the intent that started it the first time. Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357330/1482726) for a way around this.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I use the intent to create a PendingIntent that is fired by an AlarmManager, so basically the intent starts the Activity

Comment: @Lisa Anne Can you post the exception stack trace?