# Get data from URI after #

Tags: java, android

I have this URI data

```
`mari://fitbit#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI0WDVEOEgiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjdTSlkiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3Nfd`
```

And Im trying to get the access_token from the URI using this method

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (data != null){
            Log.d("Test",data.toString());
            Log.d("Access Token is: ", data.getQueryParameter("access_token"));
        }
```

However it gives me an error `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

What have I done incorrectly to access the query parameter?

Stack trace

[image]

Comment: dont you use any authorization to get the token?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what you mean. A button will open up a Fitbit website where to user gets to login to their Fitbit account . Then I'll get the access_token thru the callback

Comment: check if its a syntactical error like + operator is missing for variable side

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352281/getintent-extras-always-null

Comment: @bilalba Added in the stack trace

Comment: Try killing the app explicitly and then invoking through the intent? Does this make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Log.d("Test","" + data.toString());
 Log.d("Access Token is: ","" + data.getQueryParameter("access_token"));
```

Comment: Im not getting crashes anymore but it shows me Null

Comment: so it work ? if yas then try to add brack point and watch what type of data is coming in data variable

Comment: Seems like my access_token is null. How do I access the access_token from this URI? `mari://fitbit#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI0WDVEOEgiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjdTSlkiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3Nfd` Is getQueryParameter the correct way to do it?

Comment: sorry bro , i have no experience with this