# getIntent().getExtra() returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have code that direct users to the profile page from the bottom bar.

```
private void startNewIntent(Class className, String uid){
    Intent intent = new Intent(act, className);
    intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
    act.startActivity(intent);
    act.finish();
}

className = DisplayProfile.class;
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null){
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    startNewIntent(DisplayProfile.class, uid);
} else {
    startNewIntent(EmailPasswordActivity.class);
}
```

in ProfileActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String uid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
    if(uid != null){
        ...
    }
}
```

I also tried with `Bundle = getIntent().getExtra()` with the same results.  I have seen similar questions.  This seem to be the case: [getIntent() Extras always NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352281/getintent-extras-always-null)

I tried

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

but `getIntent().getExtra != null` is still false.

Thank you for your help and advice.

Edit: added context for startNewIntent()

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but what is `act`?

Comment: Activity act i guess ?

Comment: is getIntent() null or just getExtra()  ??

Comment: act is the current activity from which will launch the ProfileActivity.  I checked that getIntent() isn't null and it seems to be correct Intent.

Comment: what's the `launchMode` of the ProfileActivity?

Comment: why does it say 'act' and not 'this' ?  what do you mean by "bottom bar".  have you verified that the variable is not null in the first place (being but into the intent as null to begin with... or being send to the startNewIntent() method as null)?

Comment: show how are you calling `startNewIntent` method

Comment: Only getExtra is null.  I made an edit with startNewIntent context.

Comment: I don't quite understand the launch mode question

Answer (score 2):

Rather than checking in onCreate() check in onNewIntent():

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String uid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
        if(uid != null){
            ...
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        String uid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
        if(uid != null){
            ...
        }
    }
```

If it's coming in onNewIntent() this means you are using launchMode for your activity. So this is the behaviour of launch mode.

Comment: Can you explain launchMode to me?  Thank you

Comment: In the android activity, there are four types of activity launch modes. standard, singleTop, singleTask, singleInstance. These four are used to manage activity flow with stack management. For more details follow android:launchMode at: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: There was the same problem when returning to the MainActivity and invoke getExtra() from onResume(). This variant solved the problem.

Comment: I had to use like this after updating to compileSdkVersion 30. Always worked before directly at onCreate... i don't know what happened here.

Comment: @ThalisVilela this is not due to compileSdkVersion 30 or any other just check your AndroidManifest.xml for launch mode added to that particular activity tag or not? Might be you are launching activity with any intent flag which is generating this cause

Comment: @ReadyAndroid, i didn't change the manifest in a long time, perhaps the startActivity without flags are defaulting to a different mode. In this particular case, i'm using startActivityForResult by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `".class"` if already present in your class name.

```
public void startNewIntent(Class className, String uid){
Intent intent = new Intent(act.this, className+".class");
intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Next Phase

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String uid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("uid");
if(uid != null){
    ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Why should we check null condition?we kept "uid" value there