# Always getting data null from notification intent android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

Always getting bundle null....

This is my code;

```
  edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);

    String msg=edt.getText().toString();

    //create Intent
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ScondActivity.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    //Here I pass Data;
    myIntent.putExtra("msg",msg);

    //Initialize PendingIntent
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //Initialize NotificationManager using Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Create listener to listen button click
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Prepare Notification Builder
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification Demo").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(edt.getText().toString());
            //add sound
            Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            notificationBuilder.setSound(uri);
            //vibrate
            long[] v = {500,1000};
            notificationBuilder.setVibrate(v);
            notificationBuilder .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    };
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

ScondActivity.java

```
public class ScondActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.msglayout);

}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.msg);

    if(extras != null) {
        String tabNumber = extras.getString("msg");
        textView.setText(tabNumber);
        Log.d("TEMP", "Tab Number: " + tabNumber);

    } else {
        Log.d("TEMP", "Extras are NULL");
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: In second activity, when I click on notification

Comment: I enter text in edit text which is show by notification on button click and when I click on notification I want to show that text in Textview which is in SecondActivity

Comment: remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Comment: still I getting blank TextView

Comment: @VishalVaishnav As i told you use that method.

Comment: I already use ...not working

Comment: @VishalVaishnav kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352281/getintent-extras-always-null

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No it will not create any issue

Comment: I tried that .....still unable to get data

Comment: @Piyush Ji, User using `onNewIntent`

Comment: @VishalVaishnav have you added single-task or single-top launch mode in Android manifest file for ScondActivity

Comment: Can u help me how to added that in Menifest. I added that in ScondActivity programmatically. that doesn't work

Comment: sorry ,this is also not work in my case....@ChetanJoshi

Comment: @VishalVaishnav have you added that launch mode in the manifest.

Comment: Yaa bt that is not helpful to me

Comment: I don't know that newIntent is not working in your case. Just debug your code.

Comment: I solved my problem without using newIntent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve my problem.....I defined Intent for SecondActivity out side the button click event .So, I got bundle blank.My code is look like this....

```
 edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);

    //create Intent

    //Create listener to listen button click
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Prepare Notification Builder

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("msg",edt.getText().toString());
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );

            //Initialize PendingIntent
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            //Initialize NotificationManager using Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification Demo").
                            setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                            setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(edt.getText().toString());
            //add sound
            Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            notificationBuilder.setSound(uri);
            notificationBuilder .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //vibrate
            long[] v = {500,1000};
            notificationBuilder.setVibrate(v);
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    };
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Could you please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49891050/8027365)

Answer (score 1):

Get your data in `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
 {
   super.onNewIntent(intent);
   //code
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not calling ? How do you know  that it's not calling ?

Comment: cozzz I define TextView in OnCreate() and I got nothing in TextView.So we can expect this function is not calling

Comment: This is override method and you need to implement in your activity. Also retrieve data through `String tabNumber = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        textView.setText(tabNumber);` in `onNewIntent` method.

Comment: still I always get Bundle null...see my updated code

Comment: Change this `Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();` And you'r passing data in `NotificationActivity` and retrieving in `ScondActivity` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151679/discussion-between-vishal-vaishnav-and-piyush).

Comment: @Piyush hello sir could you please check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49891050/8027365)  I'm stuck in this from last 1 day

Comment: Did you call `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method in your class ??