# Opening an Activity from a notification -Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I am using `GCMBaseIntentService` in my service class which extends `GCMBaseIntentService` I override the method `onMessage(Context,Intent)`. 
The code goes here :

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");

    //String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
    String id=intent.getExtras().getString("event_id");
    String message=intent.getExtras().getString("title");
    String eventname=intent.getExtras().getString("event_name");

    generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), id, message, eventname);  
}

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String id, String message, String eventname) 
{
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

   //new intent
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EventDescription.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("event_id", id);//need this id in the eventdescription activity

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, eventname, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification); 
}
```

The problem is that, while I click this notification and in the `Eventdescription` activity  and extract the extras from intent and print the ID. It shows the correct value only the first time, after that for every notification it just shows the 1st value all the time. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, **uniqueKey**, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Please note requestCode of the getActivity of Pending intent should be unique.So just pass

unique value for every notification.You can put time stamp or even the id which you receive

from the server. I have tried this and this works.Do share your feedback

Comment: Are you able to get multiple notifications or you are checking for only one notification at a time. Also have you checked whether String id=intent.getExtras().getString("event_id");value which you are passing to generateNotification is different?

Comment: and i cant check this value..with a toast.  I used file I/O in the OnMessage() function, and the value of message is the newone..

Comment: Newone means.. latest , i.e it always changes but while i use String id=intent.getExtras().getString("event_id") in the activity, it still shows the prev value..

Comment: Can you please share a bit more code snippets of th flow i.e from where are you passing this id value to the generateNotification() and in where are you extracting the value.

Comment: Okay, I am using GCM (Google's Cloud Messaging service) It is sent from a webserver.

Comment: Hey...  superb... It worked. I saw so many tutorials regarding it, searched through the internet a lot, but finally now I got the solution. Highly Appreciable...  :-) :-) :-)  Thankyou soo much... :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**);

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notificationsfinal);


    start=1;
    end=15;

    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nextbtn);
    prev=(Button)findViewById(R.id.prevbtn);
    statusview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);


    notification_list_view=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.not_listview);
    updatestatus();
    getNotifications();

}
private void getNotifications()
{
    eventnotifierapp app=(eventnotifierapp)getApplication();



    id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("event_id");
    db=new MyDB(this);
    }
```

This is my EventDescription activity where i am retreiving this event_id

Answer (score 0):

Your subsequent `Intent`s aren't different enough, so they're being recycled. Specifically, changing the `extras` doesn't make a distinct Intent from the perspective of the system.

The docs for [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) explain that you will need to change one or more of: action, data, type, class, and categories. One approach, therefore, is to stick some distinguishing information (in your case the `event_id`) into the data URI; you don't have to use this URI for anything but it ensures that your intents will be distinct.

There's more info in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514750).